# How to mock the object returned from DB base on the parameter received?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method to query a user from DB. It will return the user if the ID is matched and date created is within a specific days

```
public User findUserCreatedLastTwoDays (String id, Date dateAccepted)
    // select * from User u where u.id = id and u.dateCreated > dateAccepted
    return User;
```

I want to write a Unit Test for this simple method using Mockito. I just start learning Mockito and not sure how can I mock the User object to test 2 different scenarios, when the dateCreated > dateAccepted (return the User) and when dateCreated < dateAccepted (return null).

Will I need to write some conditions like this

```
User testUser = new User();
testUser.setDateCreated(new Date() - 3);

if (dateCreated > dateAccepted)
    when(findUserCreatedLastTwoDays(id, dateAccepted)).thenReturn(testUser);
else 
    when(findUserCreatedLastTwoDays(id, dateAccepted)).thenReturn(null);
```

Just look for some idea how can I implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to use an [Answer](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```java
when(findUserCreatedLastTwoDays(id, dateAccepted)).thenAnswer(new Answer<User> () {
    User answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return dateCreated > dateAccepted ? testUser : null;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that the current value at the time is used and not the value when the mock was created. If this is not important for you, you can also use the suggested code:

```java
if (dateCreated > dateAccepted) {
    when(findUserCreatedLastTwoDays(id, dateAccepted)).thenReturn(testUser);
} else {
    when(findUserCreatedLastTwoDays(id, dateAccepted)).thenReturn(null);
}
```